# PHP count session variables starting with FAVORITE-LISTING-

Tags: php, session-variables

With PHP I want to count the session variables $_SESSION key that start with a particular string.

eg:

```
FAVORITE-LISTING-04
FAVORITE-LISTING-24
FAVORITE-LISTING-58
```

with the above keys, count for "FAVORITE-LISTING-" will return: 3

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING-04'] = "foo";
    $_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING-24'] = "foo";
    $_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING-58'] = "foo";

    $count = substr_count(implode(array_keys($_SESSION)), "FAVORITE-LISTING-");
    echo $count;

?>
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this working using a variable-variable which PHP does support. But I suggest instead to use a double array:

```
$_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING']['4'] = 'something';
$_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING']['24'] = 'something';
$_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING']['58'] = 'something';
count($_SESSION['FAVORITE-LISTING']);
```

That way you can retrieve data much easier and things keep organized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went with Rizier123's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$_SESSION` is an array, just loop through it and look at the key's. Anytime a key begins with whatever you're string is you just add one more to the count. Since you're look for the beginning of the string, you want [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to equal 0 so you need to use `===` instead of `==`.

```
$find = 'FAVORITE-LISTING-';
$count = 0;
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, $find) === 0) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Went with Rizier123's answer.